# why the icon is shown on site in php

Tags: php, routes

I have worked in PHP and recently use the routing in my site. but when I live my site it do not show any fontawesome or google font on site.the link of the site is https://yourguide.city/ the site is working properly but i uploaded the routing file all fontawesome fonts are removed. how to solve this problem.

Comment: I am seeing path like:  https://yourguide.city/assets/vendor/boxicons/fonts/boxicons.woff2, Please make sure path is ok.

Comment: so jo told me to add the routing of the files of the project?

Comment: "_why the icon is shown on site in php_" Which icon is shown?

Comment: the fontawsome icon is not shown which came from fontawsome website is not shown when I love the website but it is shown in localhost.